# Jersey QueryParam is received as null

Tags: java, json, jersey, jsonp

I am creating a Jersey web service with dropwizard. The client is using `JsonP` for cross domain ajax messages.

I got a resource method which looks like this:

```
@Path("/addUser")
@GET
@UnitOfWork
public String registerPortalUser(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @QueryParam("callback") String callback, @QueryParam("thedata") MyClass recordData) throws Throwable
{ .. }
```

I get the callback parameter as I expect, but instead of receiving a single Json string which is supposed to be injected to the `MyClass` member, I get many parameters which are all the MyClass member names and its values. Meaning, instead of receiving everything as a single Json string, I get all the members apart.

What can cause this?

Comment: Add your MyClass object to the question since this will most likely be the problem here. And please add a sample request you are making

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the client.
The client sent a json like this:

```
var thedata = 
{ 
   member1 = "value1",
   member2 = "value2"
}
```

What solved it was sending it like this:

```
var thedata=
[ thedata:
  {
    member1 = "value1",
    member2 = "value2"
  }
]
```

After changing it, Jersey recognized it as the requested parameter

Comment: Can you post your client code so that the rest of us (looking at this) don't make the same mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently sending a null MyClass object to the server. Your client code might look like

```
      MyClass myC = new MyClass();
    //populate MyClass fields
      WebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8088/YourWebApp").build()); 


      String res =(String) target.path("addUser").queryParam("thedata", myC).request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
```